# mysql optimization - join not using primary key when it says it is

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am having problems optimizing a query in our system. I have stripped down the table descriptions, leaving the pertinent fields. What I don't understand is why it starts with essentially a scan of the gigantic sold_data table, but seems to ignore the primary key - finding more rows (1,724,112) in that table than exist with the "mls_id = 'FL-REG'" value? This query is taking an inordinant amount of time.

One thing I just noticed is that the default character sets are different between the two tables. Hoping that isn't the (an) issue.

```
CREATE TABLE `FL_REG_IDX_CORE` (
  `mls_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mls_no` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT 'A',
  `address` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `price` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `office` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `agent` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mls_id`,`mls_no`),
  KEY `fast_city` (`status`,`city`),
  KEY `agent` (`agent`),
  KEY `office` (`office`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


ROWS by status:
| status | count(*) |
+--------+----------+
| A      |   26,620 |
| P      |    5,233 |
| S      |  701,762 |


CREATE TABLE `sold_data` (
  `mls_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mls_no` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sold_price` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sold_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`mls_id`,`mls_no`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Total Rows: 45,331,566
Rows with mls_id = 'FL-REG': 701,762



explain
SELECT *
FROM FL_REG_IDX_CORE CORE
JOIN sold_data SOLD ON CORE.mls_id = SOLD.mls_id
                AND CORE.mls_no = SOLD.mls_no 
                AND SOLD.mls_id = 'FL-REG'
WHERE ( CORE.mls_id = 'FL-REG' )
AND CORE.status = 'S'
AND CORE.city = 'North Palm Beach'
AND CORE.agent = 'Paul Portugal'

+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                           | key     | key_len | ref        | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | SOLD  | ref    | PRIMARY                                                 | PRIMARY | 22      | const      | 1724112 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | CORE  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fast_city,fast_state,fast_type_city_state,agent | PRIMARY | 124     | const,func |       1 | Using where |
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "CORE.mls_id = 'FL-REG'" doesn't use index. You have index on 2 columns so it won't work when searching by one column. The other thing is that you should create some table "cities" and create city/id pairs inside and then search by city_id key. What you are doing is searching millions of strings. It can't work fast.

Comment: @ElChupacabra since the key is `(mls_id, mls_no)` it will work when used with `mls_id` - it's just no key, when working with `mls_no`.

Comment: "You have index on 2 columns so it won't work when searching by one column" Index(mls_id, mls_no) when you use WHERE mls_id = 1` it still can use a index @ElChupacabra only `WHERE mls_no = 2` can't use a index.. but it's easy solvable by using `WHERE mls_id > 0 AND mls_no = 2` for example.

Comment: As your `explain` shows, both queries are using the primary key. Your problem is the join condition `CORE.mls_no = SOLD.mls_no`, since `mls_no` is no key (only the second part of a composite key), hence the full table scan to get that join done.

Comment: @dognose - but shouldn't the mls_id part of that key at least limit the scan to the records where mls_id = 'FL-REG'? Which is a much smaller set than the number of records that are being scanned (700K vs 1.7M).  Well, obviously it doesn't, so I'm back to the drawing board. This query is taking upwards of 20 seconds at the moment, which might as well be an eternity.

Comment: @AndyWallace Yes, Queries taking "ages" are pain in the a**.... I'm not a professional database-artist, but I think, that adding another (independent) Index on `mls_no` would cause an significant improve on query time...

A second thought would be to replace the `(inner) join` with another, more specific join, like `left join` or `right join` depending on the result you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @dognose. putting a new index on a 45M row table should be fun.. 8-)

Comment: @RaymondNijland - No.  While adding `mls_id > 0` may trick it into using the index, it cannot use the index efficiently -- it will do a full index scan.

Comment: @AndyWallace - Adding an index to a 45M-row table will take time _in older versions of MySQL_; it is less invasive in _newer_ versions.

Comment: @RickJames indeed that trick of mine will trigger a full index scan but it will be faster then a full table scan assuming the index data is smaller then the actual data what is likly 9 out the ten times.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Yes. Point made.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - sadly, mls_id is a string. so > 0 won't do it. 8-/  This thread has been very helpful, we have a couple of avenues to try.

Comment: @AndyWallace it was a example if mis_id is a (var)char you should be able to do mis_id > 'a' instead.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland, I figured as much after I looked at it for a second. > 'A' would be better, though, at least in ASCII.  8-)   We're going to hit the character set first, try this incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question by noticing that the `CHARACTER SETs` are different.  The difference for the table is *not* important; the difference for the columns in the `JOIN` *is* important.  The Optimizer throws up its hands when trying to compare columns in different `CHARACTER SET` or `COLLATION`.  This leads to a table scan instead of using an index; hence "inordinant amount of time".

Use `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...` on *one* of the tables to convert to the charset of the other.  This will correctly convert the encoding at the same time as changing the definition.

The names smell like US-only, so probably latin1 would suffice.

`status`, `state`, `zip` should not be utf8; they should be `ascii` (or `latin1` because they don't need to bulk or overhead of utf8.

Yes, add `INDEX(mls_no)` if there is a need for such.  The existing `(mls_id, mls_no)` cannot be use when testing only for `mls_no`.

You should not have `= 'FL-REG'` in the `ON`; `ON` should be used only for specifying how the tables are related.  There is no need to `= 'FL-REG'` for both tables; the Optimizer will infer it from `CORE.mls_id = SOLD.mls_id`.  (This paragraph does not impact correctness or performance, only 'style'.)

To further speed up the query, change `INDEX(status, city)` to `INDEX(status, city, agent)`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to the information I got from all these posts, we converted the encoding of some tables so that everything was utf8 (not going to mess with different encodings for specific columns).

And it worked. queries that were taking 30 seconds and longer came down to 1 or 2 seconds, sometimes less. We will have some more tweaking to do, but the worst of it it handled.

Lesson learned? Match up character encodings across tables when you want to do joins.

THanks!